# How to find closest number with function score query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to find the closest address from the source data. Using bool query searching for several columns

for exapmle:
I have several columns, all of them are string except "address_num" - is integer.
To be clear, I have two columns for address:
"address" - string, because many of them have letters inside, e.g. 24 bld 3, 45A etc,
"address_num" - integer contain only first digits

```
{
   "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
                { "match": {"admin3":  {"boost": 1, "query": region, "fuzziness": 2}}},
                { "match": {"admin4":  {"boost": 1, "query": district, "fuzziness": 2}}},
                { "match": {"admin5":  {"boost": 1, "query": settlement, "fuzziness": 2}}},
                { "match": {"base_name":  {"boost": 1, "query": base_street_name, "fuzziness":
                2}}},
                { "match": {"st_type": {"boost": 1, "query": street_type, "fuzziness": 2}}},
                { "match": {"address": {"boost": 1, "query": "24", "fuzziness": 2}}}     
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "exp": {
            "address_num": {
              "origin": "24",
              "scale": "1",
              "decay": 0.999
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So in this example I try to find address in some area with address 24. This building doesn't exist,
but there is 25 on this street, but this query returns me house with 14 address.

Alse I tried with "sort"

```
{
   "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
                { "match": {"admin3":  {"boost": 1, "query": region, "fuzziness": 2}}},
                { "match": {"admin4":  {"boost": 1, "query": district, "fuzziness": 2}}},
                { "match": {"admin5":  {"boost": 1, "query": settlement, "fuzziness": 2}}},
                { "match": {"base_name":  {"boost": 1, "query": base_street_name, "fuzziness":
                2}}},
                { "match": {"st_type": {"boost": 1, "query": street_type, "fuzziness": 2}}},
                { "match": {"address": {"boost": 1, "query": "24", "fuzziness": 2}}}     
          ]
        }
      },
      "sort": {
            "_script": {
              "type": "number",
              "script": {
                  "source":  "params.distance - doc['address_num'].value",
                "params": {
                    "distance": 24
                }
              },
              "order": "asc"
            }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

but this query returns me runtime error'

How can I get closest address?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to normalize your data and use geo locations. It'll be sustainable for future and Elasticsearch is fully compatible with it thanks to geo_point field type.

You can calculate/measure the difference between the geo points [Geo-distance query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) or you can boost the score for the nearest point with [Distance feature query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-distance-feature-query.html).

#### edit

If you are looking for the closest number of a number you can use the following _search.

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "number": 10
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "number": 20
}

PUT my_index/_doc/3
{
  "number": 30
}
```

---

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "source": "Math.abs(doc['number'].value - params.target)",
          "params": {
            "target": 26
          }
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not about geo query at all. The idea is to find address from the string

Comment: You're welcome, simply are you looking for the closest number of a number?

Comment: I edited my answer maybe it's what you are looking for, please check and let me know

Comment: Thanks, as you can see in the description above, I used pretty the same query with "sort" and it returns me runtime error. It is strange, my table is about 20M rows

Comment: Yes I saw you're using almost the same query. It works for me, what about your side? Is it worked? Is it help you to find the solution?

Comment: No, it's not work for me, got runtime error. Eventually I moved sort section further in my backend app

Comment: I test it with ES version 8